# What is the maximum time-span of a referee?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I applied for a PhD program in 2017 and got rejected. I'm preparing to apply again in 2018.

Could a professor who gave me a recommendation letter last year refuse to do so again? If so, why, and how could I approach this issue? Is there any unwritten rule regarding how long a referee will provide a reference for a student?

Comment: Sure... what is your genuine question?

Comment: If there were an unwritten rule, it'd probably be about a minimum period (e.g. one application cycle) rather than a maximum one.

Comment: Make it easier for the professor to say *yes* by attaching their original recommendation letter to your request. They'll most likely use the same letter or a slight variant of it, because their impression probably hasn't changed (at least, you don't suggest that it might).

Comment: Just relax.  Whether or not there's a "maximum time span", it's certainly much more than a year.  Barring something very unusual, this is not going to be a problem in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there are cultural differences, but when I am writing a letter of reference for a student, it will hold lifelong. The rationale is simple:

- It has a date on it, so the other side can see when it was issued and decide by themselfes how valid my interpretation of the student's performance is at the current date
- I'm writing my true opinion on the student, there is no reason to change my mind.
- If someone want's an updated version, they can call / contact me via e-mail.

I know of no official or inofficial rules (in Germany).

The situation might be different if you need a *new* reference letter. Then I would only write it if I can tell something new about you.

So if you need an updated letter of reference, the referee should recieve some content from your side to put into this letter, together with a brief explanation of your goals, how you improved, etc.

Comment: What happens to electronic references?

Comment: What is an "electronic reference"? An e-mail? I see no difference if it's an e-mail

Answer (score 3):

In the Graduate School I manage, we require reference letters to be submitted with, among other things:

1. a clear date when it was prepared
2. an estimate of the length of time the referee has known the applicant and
3. a description of the capacity in which the referee knows the applicant.

For example:

> 09 September 2017
>
> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> I have known Ms Wenting LIANG for three years. During that time, I was her thesis adviser, served as her academic adviser and taught her in three courses (STA101 Introduction to Statistics, STA305 Statistical Inference, STA311 Simulation).
>
> ...
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Professor James Carruthers

With this information, assessors are able to situate the reference letter in the context of the rest of the evidence provided by the applicant.

In answer to your questions:

> Could it happen that the professor who previously supplied him reference refuses to do so again? If Yes, why?

Yes. This can happen for all sorts of reasons, some being more personal than others. For example, the professor may have not changed his assessment of the applicant and the original reference letter holds despite the applicant's claimed additional "preparation", or he may be reluctant to assert that the work done by the applicant *after* the original reference letter is of any value, or a million other reasons.

> And, how should one approach this issue?

There's nothing you can do about this. Someone not willing to write you a new reference letter has given you their answer. Thank them for their time and look for a referee who will.

> Is there any unwritten rule regarding how long a referee would provide a reference for a student?

None that I am aware, at least in Australia, the UK, Southeast Asia and East Asia where I have worked. We're looking for relevance, not at dates.

Good luck!